# Implementing custom UITabBarController without private APIs

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

After searching through several question on StackOverflow I've found out that there is only 1 major project for creating custom UITabBar called `BCTabBarController`. The description to it says:

> There are several problems with using the standard UITabBarController
>   including:
>
> It is too tall, especially in landscape mode
>
> The height doesn't match the UIToolbar
>
> It *cannot be customized without using private APIs*

Nevertheless, I've found [this strange project on GitHub](https://github.com/rumex/RXCustomTabBar) with the [tutorial here](http://www.rumex.it/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/) that uses standard `UITabBarController` in its implementation with `UIButtons` for each tab and it's working (strangely enough, but it does).

I was wondering, if this is wrong to create your custom `UITabBarController` with `UIButtons` instead of tabs and what would it result into? The implementation of this looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self hideTabBar];
    [self addCustomElements];
}

- (void)hideTabBar
{
    for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            view.hidden = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)addCustomElements
{
    // Initialise our two images
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar_01.png"];
    UIImage *btnImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar_01_s.png"];

    self.btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; //Setup the button
    btn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 430, 80, 50); // Set the frame (size and position) of the button)
    [btn1 setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // Set the image for the normal state of the button
    [btn1 setBackgroundImage:btnImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected]; // Set the image for the selected state of the button
    btn1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [btn1 setTag:0]; // Assign the button a "tag" so when our "click" event is called we know which button was pressed.
    [btn1 setSelected:true]; // Set this button as selected (we will select the others to false as we only want Tab 1 to be selected initially
```

In my project I will be using iOS 5.1 and up and no Storyboards or XIBs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS 5.0, it is no longer a problem to create your own `UITabBarController` using a line of `UIButtons` at the bottom of the screen.

In previous versions of the iOS SDK, it was a bit risky as you had to manage the forwarding of the `viewWill/viewDid`methods by yourself.

Have a look at the `UIViewController` Class Reference, section **Implementing a Container View Controller**, you will find all you need there : [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

There is also a featured article explaining exactly what you need : [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Hope this will help,