# UIStoryboard loadNibNamed analog method

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I use this tutorial to achieve my custom `UITabBarController`: [link](https://github.com/aalittle/ALCustomTabBarController)

But I use storyboard instead of xibs. So some of method use this code below:

```
NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TabBarView" owner:self options:nil];
```

It is fair for xib but as I think not for storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for u

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerName"];
```

Dont forget to give identifier to your viewcontroller inside the storyboard.

Note:- Make sure you have given `ViewControllerWithIdentifier` in storyboard.

Comment: i need to get just view from it.

Comment: once you get viewcontroller the you can easily get its subviews via iboutlets or tags

Comment: yes you are right, so what about clear code is this good solution. or maybe we need to make ui objects via code? what do you think

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid storyboards are not well suited for this kind of task. There is no method for getting a specific view from a `UIStoryboard` instance.

In this case, I would recommend you to create a separate xib file with just the view you want to load on its own and use the code you gave to load it.

On a side note I would also not recommend using a library which has 3 years since the last commit, specially with iOS 7 out which breaks a lot of things.

Comment: yes I have modified the library and seems the logic works good

Comment: i think there is nothing criminal to inherit UITabBarController and hide its subviews like UITabBar. What do you think?

Comment: It depends on how much you'll need to customize. If you are creating the whole view again, I would follow the route pointed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201870/implementing-custom-uitabbarcontroller-without-private-apis)